# Volume mounted configmap, by label selector

Tags: kubernetes

I'm looking for a way to mount configs based on label selector.

I will have new configmap's created over time, which I will label with "intendeedtarget"="MainApp".
The configs are created from json file, with filename as key.

E.g. a yml something like this (but working):

```
    volumeMounts:
      - name: appconfigs
        mountPath: /appconfigs
  volumes:
  - name: appconfigs
    configMap:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          intendeedtarget: MainApp
```

That is new configs will be auto mounted in the running pods for the "MainApp" over time.

I have already gotten it to mount individual configs as files in the running pods with:

```
containers:
      - name: {{Name}}
        image: {{Image}}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - name: appconfigs
            mountPath: /appconfigs
      volumes:
      - name: appconfigs
        configMap:
          name: {{ConfigName}}
```

This mounts the json applied to the configmap, as a separate file in the /appconfigs folder.

My goal now is to mount all configmaps with the label "intendeedtarget" = "MainApp" in /appconfigs.

Any suggestions?

A bonus question, does anyone know how to label a configmap as one command, i.e. when creating the configmap?

BR

Comment: If it's not possible, that answer would be helpful as well..

Comment: _A bonus question, does anyone know how to label a configmap as one command, i.e. when creating the configmap?_ assuming you are using `kubectl create -f`, the answer is to put the `labels:` key under `metadata:`, in exactly the same manner as one finds from `kubectl get -o yaml configmap $SomeConfigMapName`

Answer (score 4):

So the short version is no, one cannot specify a whole range of volumeMounts, but there is a work-around available to you: `initContainers:`

I believe it would work like this:

1. The Pod would declare a `volume` of type `emptyDir`, named `appconfigs` *(just to make discussing it easy, the name isn't important)* mounted where you wish. It is of type `emptyDir` because we only care about having some shared disk space between the `initContainer` and the "main" `containers`, and that shared space should evaporate when the Pod does
2. The `initContainer` would either have a `kubectl` binary in it, or download one, or use one of the many, many kubernetes api client libraries, or even just a copy of `curl` in it

   1. using the `ServiceAccount` token, it queries for the `ConfigMap`s of your choosing. It is absolutely possible to put the label criteria into an environment variable of the `initContainer`, or the `initContainer` can even use the metadata of its own Pod for introspection, if you prefer that
   2. It extracts their payloads, massages them as you wish, and writes the files into the mount point of `appconfigs`
3. Now the `containers:` will start, but it will find the config files in the shared volume mount, just as you specified

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I was stuck on the same problem.
The solution proposed by mdaniel works fine, but there is also a project by kiwigrid which does the same thing for you: https://github.com/kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar.
You can add the container as a sidecar, as described in the [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/).
Configuration of is done via env variables, so for example you could use:

```yaml
- name: appconfig-sidecar
  image: kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:1.19.2
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  volumeMounts:
  - name: appconfigs
    mountPath: /appconfigs
  env:
  - name: LABEL
    value: "intendeedtarget"
  - name: LABEL_VALUE
    value: "MainApp"
  - name: FOLDER
    value: "appconfigs"
```

Other options can be found in the repo.